# Definitions of lift contradictory?

Tags: data-mining

I understand that lift is a the ratio of the observed support to the expected one if X and Y were independent. Looking at [independence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_%28probability_theory%29#Definition) it would make sense to define it as follows: $$\frac{\mathrm{P}(X \cap Y)}{ \mathrm{P}(X)\mathrm{P}(Y)}$$

Exactly this is done in the Wikipedia article on lift: [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lift_%28data_mining%29)

Yet in another Wikipedia article on [association rule learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_rule_learning#Useful_Concepts) (and in fact in many other publications on data mining and association rules, like e.g. [here](http://books.google.de/books?id=mDs7OXj03V0C&lpg=PA196&dq=data%20mining%20with%20rattle%20and%20r%2010.3%20measures&pg=PA196#v=onepage&q&f=false)) I find this definition:$$\frac{\mathrm{P}(X \cup Y)}{ \mathrm{P}(X)\mathrm{P}(Y)}$$

**My question**
Which definition is correct or are both equivalent (if yes, how)?

Comment: This question appears to be based on a misreading of the [second Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_rule_learning#Useful_Concepts). Did you note the passage "Be careful when reading the expression: here supp$X\cup Y$ means "support for occurrences of transactions where $X$ and $Y$ both appear", not "support for occurrences of transactions where either $X$ or $Y$ appears""?

Comment: @whuber: Well, I don't know - I added another reference in the question where the second def is being used (unfortunately page 197 where the actual def of lift is printed cannot be seen but it is based on the support def on page 196 which is visible)

Comment: You are persisting in the same misreading: "support" is not quite the same as "probability" and, more importantly, the senses in which "$\cup$" are used are not the same, either. Looking carefully at the definitions in your references might resolve your question immediately.

Comment: ...besides: I thought that in all cited cases support means that $X$ and $Y$ both appear.

Comment: Please re-read the quotation from the Wikipedia definition.

Comment: I still don't understand. How is support different in the first and the second def? And coming from independence I think only the first def makes sense. Sorry for still being confused...

Comment: In the same passage, Wikipedia explains "The argument of $\mathrm{supp}()$ is a set of preconditions, and thus becomes more restrictive as it grows (instead of more inclusive)."